# When debugging, quick doc window covers variable value window

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I checked `Settings -> Editor -> Show quick doc on mouse move`, which makes it like Visual Studio and Eclipse.

But when I enter debug mode, I hover my cursor on variables, Android Studio also shows the doc of the type of the variable, and the doc window covers the variable value window, like the figure below.

[image]

How can I see the value window? VS or Eclipse doesn't show quick doc in debug mode.

Comment: Try right click on variable and inspect variable value like eclipse if available in Android Studio.

Comment: @sanatshukla right click, evaluate, ok. Three clicks is too much

Comment: Good question, I am also completely confounded by this behavior. It's absolutely braindead to have the quick-doc-on-hover feature work this way.

I can only conclude the users of the quick-doc-on-hover feature don't actually debug anything. Must be a different use case for the IDE.